# Meteor helper not updating

Tags: meteor

Meteor not updating helper function. It returns the vales but not update.

```
Template.recrutersubscription.helpers({
    renderskills: function ()
    {
        console.log(">>>>>>>>>>skilldropdown");
        console.log(Session.get('skilldropdown'));

        return Session.get('skilldropdown');
    }
});
```

And this my Html code

```
<select id="example-multiple-requiredskill" multiple="multiple">
  <optgroup label="Skills">
    {{{renderskills}}}
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Please add the code where you set your `skilldropdown` Session variable.

Comment: where are you setting the `skilldropdown` Session? and isn't it supposed to be two curly braces in `{{{renderskills}}}`

Comment: @sdybskiy Triple-curly braced template tags `{{{…}}}` are used in spacebars to include raw HTML within the page.

Comment: @Billybobbonnet thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: Is there oncomplete or callback for the helper function.@Billybobbonnet

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using the reactive var properly? From where is this data coming from?

Be sure to follow this path:

```
var reactiveWhatever = new ReactiveVar({});

template.onCustomCreated = function() {
  return reactiveWhatever.set({
    whatever: true
  });
};

Template.recrutersubscription.helpers(
renderskills: function ()
    {
        console.log(">>>>>>>>>>skilldropdown");
        console.log(Session.get('skilldropdown'));

        return reactiveWhatever.get('skilldropdown');
    }
);
```

and then in the HTML

```
<select id="example-multiple-requiredskill" multiple="multiple">
  <optgroup label="Skills">
    {{{renderskills}}}
  </optgroup>
</select>
```